# How to insert data in a XML sub tag

Tags: php, html, xml

let's suppose that i have this tag

```
<root>
<foo> </foo>
</root>
```

with this html form

```
<form action="foo.php method="post">
<input type="text" name="something">
<input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

if I want to insert data I do

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok'])) {
$data=simplexml_load_file('foo.xml') or die('error');

if(isset($_POST['something'])) {    
    $data->foo= $_POST['something'];
}
```

it work nicely without any problem now if we want to insert a data in the sub tag

```
<root>
  <foo>
   <test></test>
  </foo>
</root>
```

I thought we should do something like

```
if(isset($_POST['something'])) {    
    $data->foo->test= $_POST['something'];
}
```

let's suppose that we have "hello" in `$_POST['something']` variable
I expected to have something like

```
<root>
  <foo> 
   <test>Hello</test>
  </foo>
</root>
```

but it does not work

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your expected output?

Comment: ok @JackFleeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $root=simplexml_load_file("file.xml") or die("Error"); // first we load the file
    if(isset($_POST['ok'])){ // if we validate the form
    $something= $_POST['something']; // we recover the data with POST
    // let assume that we have 'hello' inside $something
    $root->foo->test = $something; //then we send the data to the xml file
    $root->asXML('foo.xml');
}
```

the output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo>
   <test>Hello</test>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<root>
  <foo>
   <test></test>
  </foo>
</root>
');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('test') as $item) {
   $item->textContent="Hello";

}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo>
   <test>Hello</test>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Comment: if it is possible I want to know why my code does not work